# Caused by [Version 17.0.0.2] [Session 8085885] [Teradata SQL Driver] Failure receiving Start Response message header

Tags: python-3.x, teradata, teradatasql

I am doing an insert query using the `teradatasql` module with python and getting this error.
I am trying to run multiple scripts simultaneously and I guess I cannot do multiple insert queries at the same time?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\LAMKAJO\Desktop\Work J\Depot Capacity\Script\pac.py", line 446, in <module>
    new_main.run()

  File "C:\Users\LAMKAJO\Desktop\Work J\Depot Capacity\Script\pac.py", line 440, in run
    tc.map(self.city_calc, self.mp_city_lst)

  File "C:\Users\LAMKAJO\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 268, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()

  File "C:\Users\LAMKAJO\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value

  File "C:\Users\LAMKAJO\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))

  File "C:\Users\LAMKAJO\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))

  File "C:\Users\LAMKAJO\Desktop\Work J\Depot Capacity\Script\pac.py", line 242, in city_calc
    self.city_cluster_wk_hrs(df_lrcity,loc_sep[0],loc_sep[1])

  File "C:\Users\LAMKAJO\Desktop\Work J\Depot Capacity\Script\pac.py", line 231, in city_cluster_wk_hrs
    cur.executemany(self.insert_sql_query,dtframe.values.tolist())

  File "C:\Users\LAMKAJO\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\teradatasql\__init__.py", line 896, in executemany
    raise OperationalError (sErr)

OperationalError: [Version 17.0.0.2] [Session 8085885] [Teradata SQL Driver] [Error 528] A failure occurred while executing rows 1 through 12 of a batch request.
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).makeDriverErrorCode TeradataConnection.go:1120
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.newTeradataRows TeradataRows.go:396
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataStatement).QueryContext TeradataStatement.go:122
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).QueryContext TeradataConnection.go:2083
 at database/sql.ctxDriverQuery ctxutil.go:48
 at database/sql.(*DB).queryDC.func1 sql.go:1464
 at database/sql.withLock sql.go:3032
 at database/sql.(*DB).queryDC sql.go:1459
 at database/sql.(*Conn).QueryContext sql.go:1701
 at main.goCreateRows goside.go:654
 at main._cgoexpwrap_212fad278f55_goCreateRows _cgo_gotypes.go:357
 at runtime.call64 asm_amd64.s:574
 at runtime.cgocallbackg1 cgocall.go:316
 at runtime.cgocallbackg cgocall.go:194
 at runtime.cgocallback_gofunc asm_amd64.s:826
 at runtime.goexit asm_amd64.s:2361
Caused by [Version 17.0.0.2] [Session 8085885] [Teradata SQL Driver] Failure receiving Start Response message header
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).makeDriverError TeradataConnection.go:1101
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).sendAndReceive TeradataConnection.go:1397
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*TeradataRows).executeSQLRequest TeradataRows.go:526
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.newTeradataRows TeradataRows.go:388
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataStatement).QueryContext TeradataStatement.go:122
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).QueryContext TeradataConnection.go:2083
 at database/sql.ctxDriverQuery ctxutil.go:48
 at database/sql.(*DB).queryDC.func1 sql.go:1464
 at database/sql.withLock sql.go:3032
 at database/sql.(*DB).queryDC sql.go:1459
 at database/sql.(*Conn).QueryContext sql.go:1701
 at main.goCreateRows goside.go:654
 at main._cgoexpwrap_212fad278f55_goCreateRows _cgo_gotypes.go:357
 at runtime.call64 asm_amd64.s:574
 at runtime.cgocallbackg1 cgocall.go:316
 at runtime.cgocallbackg cgocall.go:194
 at runtime.cgocallback_gofunc asm_amd64.s:826
 at runtime.goexit asm_amd64.s:2361
Caused by read tcp 10.199.17.157:54103->10.229.115.22:1025: wsarecv: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Comment: What does "multiple insert queries at the same time" mean? Can you elaborate on the structure of your application? You can certainly run queries on different connections at the same time. If you try to run multiple queries on one connection they are likely serialized. But it isn't obvious either of those would lead to WinSock WSAETIMEDOUT error shown here.

Comment: the data dept restricted to 1 query at a time, not sure if there is a work around?